# How to create a 2D array with all possible combinations of a constrained range for each column

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have three ranges and want to create a 3 column array with every possible combination of these ranges and for it to be in a specific order. I know how to do this with a loop. However, in reality the data will have way more than 3 columns and the ranges are very large so I think a loop will be inefficient and would like a fast way of doing this. The real dataset size will be approximately 5 GB so efficiency is key for me. As an example:

```
inc = 1
a = np.arange(1001,1002+inc,inc)
b = np.arange(1,3+inc,inc)
c = np.arange(1,5+inc,inc)
```

I want to create an output that looks like:

```
array([[1001,    1,    1],
       [1001,    1,    2],
       [1001,    1,    3],
       [1001,    1,    4],
       [1001,    1,    5],
       [1001,    2,    1],
       [1001,    2,    2],
       [1001,    2,    3],
       [1001,    2,    4],
       [1001,    2,    5],
       [1001,    3,    1],
       [1001,    3,    2],
       [1001,    3,    3],
       [1001,    3,    4],
       [1001,    3,    5],
       [1002,    1,    1],
       [1002,    1,    2],
       [1002,    1,    3],
```

This output is not complete but it shows what I want. I should add that I am doing this because I have an input table of the same format but with missing rows and I want to be able to identify the missing rows by comparing the input dataset to this 'ideal' table. As mentioned above, I can do this with a for loop but want to find a more Pythonic way of doing it if possible.

Comment: I think that the python's [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you are looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily with the built-in `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools as it

perms = np.array(list(it.product(a, b, c)))
```

Output:

```
>>> perms
array([[1001,    1,    1],
       [1001,    1,    2],
       [1001,    1,    3],
       [1001,    1,    4],
       [1001,    1,    5],
       [1001,    2,    1],
       [1001,    2,    2],
       [1001,    2,    3],
       [1001,    2,    4],
       [1001,    2,    5],
       [1001,    3,    1],
       [1001,    3,    2],
       [1001,    3,    3],
       [1001,    3,    4],
       [1001,    3,    5],
       [1002,    1,    1],
       [1002,    1,    2],
       [1002,    1,    3],
       [1002,    1,    4],
       [1002,    1,    5],
       [1002,    2,    1],
       [1002,    2,    2],
       [1002,    2,    3],
       [1002,    2,    4],
       [1002,    2,    5],
       [1002,    3,    1],
       [1002,    3,    2],
       [1002,    3,    3],
       [1002,    3,    4],
       [1002,    3,    5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [numpy.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) because it runs significantly faster.

```py
>>> np.array(np.meshgrid(a,b,c)).T.reshape((-1, 3))
array([[1001,    1,    1],
       [1001,    2,    1],
       [1001,    3,    1],
       [1002,    1,    1],
       [1002,    2,    1],
       [1002,    3,    1],
       [1001,    1,    2],
       [1001,    2,    2],
       [1001,    3,    2],
       [1002,    1,    2],
```

If order is important, this seems to do it.

```py
np.array([m.flatten() for m in np.meshgrid(a,b,c, indexing='ij')]).T
```

Comment: Cool! You can also just re-index the array in your first version to get the right order: `np.array(np.meshgrid(a,b,c)).T.reshape(-1, 3)[:, [0, 2, 1]]` - but that's not very dynamic.